# SSIS Foreach Flatfile Connection issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv, foreach, ssis

I have one directory of .csv files that I want to load into a db where each table is titled after the .csv title.

I have a foreach loop to handle this.
A variable for the current dir, current file, and tblName that are all defined and modified with scripting actions.

The last command of my foreach loop updates the current File variable, but it does not seem to refresh the flat file connection as debugging fails with an error stating a column found in the previous csv is expected but not found in datasource (which is the next csv in the dir)

Control flow:
[image]

Data flow for 'insert new data from target'
[image]

and here's the code for updating the var's at the end of the for/each loop.

```
    int pos = (int)Dts.Variables["User::pos"].Value;
    string dirPath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::sourceFolder"].Value;
    pos++;
    Dts.Variables["User::pos"].Value = pos;

    //object ffConnection = Dts.Connections["CSV FILE"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
    //string filePath = (string)ffConnection;
    //MessageBox.Show(ffConnection.ToString());
    //Dts.Connections["CSV FILE"].ReleaseConnection(ffConnection);

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    FileInfo[] diAr1 = di.GetFiles("*.csv");
    FileInfo next;
    string nextPath;
    string tblName;

    //MessageBox.Show(next.FullName);

    if (diAr1.Length > 1){
        next = diAr1[pos];
        nextPath = next.FullName;
        tblName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nextPath);
        Dts.Variables["User::CurrentFile"].Value = nextPath;
        Dts.Variables["User::tblName"].Value = tblName;
        MessageBox.Show("script's tblName: " + tblName);
        MessageBox.Show("User::tblName: " + (string)Dts.Variables["User::tblName"].Value);
        MessageBox.Show("User::CurrentFile: " + (string)Dts.Variables["User::CurrentFile"].Value);
    }


    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: Show the error message. and, in what step exaclty you get the error.

Comment: [insert into table based off of tblName var [2]] Error: Column "schoolNum" cannot be found at the datasource.
[insert into table based off of tblName var [2]] Error: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: insert into table based off of tblName var failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
@Ricardo-C

Comment: ^^^ for above, the column "schoolNum" is from the first csv file processed, but the for each has moved on to the iteration of the process @ricardo